# How can i get the "Data slot" from a given R S3 object?

Tags: r

Out of curiosity, I wonder whether it's possible to extract content of "Data", as seen when I apply the R function "str". 
I can extract attributes with attr(), but what about "Data" ?

Example:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
data(edhec)

str(edhec) 

An ‘xts’ object on 1997-01-31/2009-08-31 containing:
  **Data**: num [1:152, 1:13] 0.0119 0.0123 0.0078 0.0086 0.0156 0.0212 0.0193 0.0134 0.0122 0.01 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:13] "Convertible Arbitrage" "CTA Global" "Distressed Securities" "Emerging Markets" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: GMT
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

How to get "Data" ? (I know coredata() would do the job, but my question is a general R question). As an example, attr(edhec, "index") would give me the attribute "index", but how can I access "Data" ?

Comment: The `edhec` data set is not contained in the `xts` package.

Comment: Sorry, of course it should have been  library(PerformanceAnalytics)

Comment: Just edit and I remove my downvote :)

Comment: `as.data.frame(edhec)`?

Comment: it's a general R question, don't focus on xts. In objects other than xts as.data.frame would not necessarily make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is an S3 object then this will remove all the attributes leaving the data, `x0`:

```
x0 <- x
attributes(x0) <- NULL
```

however, note that things like its names, dimensions and dimnames are attributes too so if you want to regard those as part of the data then you will need something like this:

```
x0 <- x
attnames <- names(attributes(x0))
special <- c("names", "dim", "dimnames")
attributes(x0)[setdiff(attnames, special)] <- NULL
```

Comment: In other words, I need a workaround and there is no direct access. That's what I wanted to know.  Many thanks Gabor.

Answer (score 3):

Posing this as a "general R question" suggests you have not yet understood that R is a functional language with function dispatch based on `class`-es of objects. `xts`-objects do not have are "slots"; that is an S4 R concept. The "`**Data**`"-text is a an informational label produced by the `print.xts`-function.

```
class(edhec)  .... returns  .. [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

At their "core", both zoo and xts objects are really just two-dimensional, i.e. matrix-like, objects. They do, however, have specially defined properties such as `print` and `str`. To see the `str`-methods which are available with my current workspace, I do this.

```
 methods(str)
 [1] str.data.frame*       str.Date*             str.default*          str.dendrogram*      
 [5] str.dictionary*       str.Formula*          str.gtable*           str.igraph*          
 [9] str.logLik*           str.POSIXt*           str.quosure*          str.Rcpp_stack_trace*
[13] str.uneval*           str.unit.arithmetic*  str.xts*              str.zoo*             
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

If, instead, I wanted the orthogonal approach, i.e list all the *functions* that have been defined for `xts`-objects, I would do this:

```
methods(class="xts")
 [1] [                 [<-               align.time        as.complex        as.data.frame    
 [6] as.double         as.environment    as.integer        as.list           as.logical       
[11] as.matrix         as.numeric        as.POSIXct        as.POSIXlt        as.ts            
[16] as.xts            as.zoo            as.zooreg         c                 cbind            
[21] CLASS<-           coredata          cummax            cummin            cumprod          
[26] cumsum            diff              dimnames          dimnames<-        end              
[31] first             index             index<-           indexClass<-      indexFormat<-    
[36] indexTZ           indexTZ<-         is.time.unique    lag               last             
[41] lines             make.index.unique merge             na.locf           na.omit          
[46] Ops               plot              points            print             rbind            
[51] rollapply         split             start             str               tclass<-         
[56] time<-            tzone             tzone<-           xtsAttributes<-  
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Also look at the output of

```
 methods(class="zoo")
```

And:

```
attributes(edhec)
```

And:

```
dput(edhec)
```

Notice that attempting to get a response to the question: "is an `xts`-object really an R matrix", I get:

```
> inherits(edhec, "matrix")
[1] FALSE
```

This is despite the fact that an xts-object would behave in most ways like an R matrix, since it has `dim`-ensional attributes:

```
dim(edhec)
#[1] 152  13
edhec[ 1, ]
#---------
           Convertible Arbitrage CTA Global Distressed Securities Emerging Markets
1997-01-31                0.0119     0.0393                0.0178           0.0791
           Equity Market Neutral Event Driven Fixed Income Arbitrage Global Macro
1997-01-31                0.0189       0.0213                 0.0191       0.0573
           Long/Short Equity Merger Arbitrage Relative Value Short Selling Funds of Funds
1997-01-31            0.0281            0.015          0.018       -0.0166         0.0317
```

So xts-objects are both `xts` and `zoo` objects that have their own set of accessor and operational functions. The "[" function is (perhaps) the extraction function you requested. There is no "Data" element or `Data` function. There is, of course, the `coredata` function that you did not want:

```
> is.matrix(coredata(edhec))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe could you make it clearer at the beginning of your answer that **there is no Data *slot* or *attribute* ** in a `xts` object. (Now, it comes at the end...) Similarly, how to list existing slots or attributes? Does it even make sens with S3 objects?

Comment: S3 objects (of various classes) often have attributes. In fact both `zoo` and `xts` objects are S3 objects. What they do not have are "slots", which is a S4 R concept.